# Flash player in Epiphany

Tags: flash, epiphany

I have installed Epiphany browser, and really like it because of it's startup time and small footprint. However, I am unable to make youtube or huhu videos (anything that requires flash) to run on Epiphany. Can you please help me with the configuration. I have Firefox and opera both on my system, and both are able to play Flash based videos on the web.

Comment: And what about playing videos at YouTube through HTML5? Does Epiphany support this? Then this can be a partial (only for the sites that have videos in HTML5) and more free solution to the problem.

Comment: There are TONS of videos even on youtube that won't play with HTML5. Supposedly it's because of the ads.

Answer (score 7):

Flash is GTK+2 and Epiphany is GTK+3...that's the problem.

1. install flash `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`
2. install nspluginwrapper `sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper`
3. `sudo nspluginwrapper -i
   /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`
4. `nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i`

Comment: worked for me! 11.10

Comment: didn't work in 12.04. $ sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -->
nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so

Comment: Not working for me either, but I think it's because there is no 64-bit version of nspluginviewer. I noticed it automatically installed the i386 version with the amd64 version of the wrapper, so I doubt they'll work properly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Xubuntu 12.04, the lib is in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/`.

So in my case the code is:

```
sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and in my case I installed flashplugin using Ubuntu Software Centre and so it installed the plugin at `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so`. I did following and Flash worked perfectly in Epiphany 3.4.1.

```
sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so
nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve problem with adobe flash player in epiphany 3.6 ;-)

This is what I do:

1. `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin nspluginwrapper`
2. `sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so`
3. `nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu 64-bit, `install adobe-flashplugin:i386` instead of `adobe-flashplugin`, before using `nspluginwrapper`.

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin:i386 nspluginwrapper
nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html or http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ in Epiphany.

It should show you if you have flash installed, maybe there is another issue. Flash in Epiphany worked the first time I installed it and loaded youtube.

Comment: It does not work for me on 11.10 Oneiric

Comment: I've already tried it.The problem is that Flash works with Firefox, but not Epiphany. I've manually tried adding the Libflashplayer.so file to plugins for Epiphany, but it still does not work. can u suggest any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

NPAPI plugins are (unfortunately) no longer supported by major web browsers.
PPAPI is the new way. Fortunately, a very good open source project called Freshplugin allow any browser to use flash player PPAPI from Chrome in Linux.It means that the last flash player update will be used in any browser, even epiphany. You must have Chrome installed.
https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin